# Adding custom icons with Google Maps using JSON

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I can't get a custom icon to display using this code below. It just defaults to the default Google maps marker.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
$(function() {
$('#map_canvas').gmap({ 
'center':new google.maps.LatLng(54.5,-4.0),
'zoom':6, 
'streetViewControl': false,
'callback': 


function() {
setInterval( function() {       
$.getJSON( 'URL/data_sets/json/sfuk47.php?'+ new     Date().getTime(), 'category=activity',    function(data) { 
$.each( data.markers, function(i, m) {
$('#map_canvas').gmap(
'addMarker',{
'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng) });
});             
});
}, 5000);                               
}
});
}); 

 setInterval( function() {
$.ajax({
url:'URL/data_sets/json/sfuk47.php',
success: function(data) {
if (data == "refresh"){
window.location.reload();
}
}
});
}, 600000);
```

The JSON
{"markers":[
{"lat":59.889,"lng":1.249,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"},{"lat":59.892,"lng":1.235,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"},{"lat":56.778,"lng":-5.702,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"},{"lat":49.534,"lng":-1.814,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"},{"lat":56.608,"lng":-8.324,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"},{"lat":49.286,"lng":-2.183,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"},{"lat":49.289,"lng":-2.192,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"},{"lat":59.051,"lng":-7.525,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"},{"lat":58.965,"lng":-7.439,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"},{"lat":57.531,"lng":-6.895,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"},
{"lat":56.895,"lng":-6.372,"icon":"URL/icons/gl_icons/Red.png"}]}

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance you're not setting the icon in the markers call. Try doing:

```
'addMarker',{
'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng),
'icon': m.icon });
```

But be aware you appear to be using API v2 which is deprecated.

[Some relevant examples for API V3.](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/data/importing_data)

Comment: Thanks .That done the trick. I'm using the code from an example http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-json.html How do I use API v3?

Comment: See added link. It's generally a good idea to use the latest version especially as support for API V2 has now ended.